# Why use ExecStart= (with no value) before another ExecStart=/new/value in a systemd override?

Tags: systemd

I would like to go the systemd override way to let dockerd to listen to port 2376.
So I followed this [instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configuring-remote-access-with-systemd-unit-file).

On the other hand, I would like to dig into systemd to know what's going on under the hood.
So I tried to inspect the unit file of docker by this command:
`systemctl cat docker.service`

According to the output of the command, two files are involved.

1. /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
2. /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf

I believe the first one is default unit file for docker and the second one is the I created.

My problem is:
Both files include sentances - `ExecStart=` and twice in the second file like:

```
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
```

Is it necessary to assign empty to `ExecStart=` before setting meaningful value `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` ?

I have spilit this post into two questions and the other one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68823645/3256839).

Comment: I think there are two questions here. I would suggest moving your question the `--containerd` option to a new question.

Comment: I have post another question about the `--containerd` option here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68823645/3256839

Comment: Updated the title to be narrowly a systemd question, since this applies to _all_ systemd override files that change `ExecStart`, not just the Docker ones.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you add entries to an override file, they are by default *appended* to any existing entries. That is, if your service `example.service` has:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/foo.env
```

And you create `/etc/systemd/system/example.service.d/override.conf`
with:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/bar.env
```

Then the effective configuration is:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/foo.env
EnvironmentFile=/etc/bar.env
```

That's fine for many directives, but a service can have only one
`ExecStart` (unless it's a `Type-oneshot` service), so if you try to create an override file like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/new/command/line
```

That will fail with an error along the lines of:

```
systemd: example.service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
```

By specifying an *empty* `ExecStart`, you are "clearing out" all
previous entries. So if your `example.service` has:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/foo
```

And you create an override like:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/bin/bar
```

The effective configuration is:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Very clear. :)