# What is purpose of the switch --containerd in command dockerd?

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

If I run `systemctl cat docker.service` to check the unit file of docker.service,
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock` can be found in the default unit file of docker.

My question is what is the purpose of the switch of
`--containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`?

According to the answer of [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68818218/3256839), if I generate an override file for docker.service with the content as:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
```

The effective configuration would be:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
```

and `--containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock` will be omitted.

What will happen caused by this configuration then?
I hope that docker can work properly both locally and remotely with TLS protection enabled.
I also need invoke docker daemon via ssh.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important part of the documentation is somewhat further down in the "[Docker runtime execution options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#docker-runtime-execution-options)" section, where it says:

> The Docker daemon relies on a OCI compliant runtime (invoked via the containerd daemon) as its interface to the Linux kernel namespaces, cgroups, and SELinux.
>
> By default, the Docker daemon automatically starts containerd. If you want to control containerd startup, manually start containerd and pass the path to the containerd socket using the --containerd flag.

In other words, the original Docker unit probably includes `--containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock` because `containerd` is managed by systemd `.socket` and `.service` units.

By excluding the flag from your override, my reading of the docs is that Docker will start up its own `containerd` instance rather than using the one bound to `/run/containerd/containerd.sock`.

Probably harmless, but it's probably a better idea just to add that flag to your override command line.

Comment: Got your point.  It seems like an explicit setting. I am going to keep it in my override command line in case any unexpected errors occur. :)